# Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

Tags: android, android-studio, аудио, button, imagebutton

В приложении есть ряд кнопок, которые при нажатии на них воспроизводят звук, некоторые звуки длятся меньше секунды. При нажатии на такие кнопки приложение крашится и выводит ошибку о том что файл не может быть открыт из за того что сжат.

Такая проблема только с кнопками к которым привязаны файлы со звуком меньше секунды. Как можно исправить эту ошибку ?